# Use JPA entity id without @GeneratedValue annotation

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm working with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. Should I use annotation `@GeneratedValue` on my entity id if my code working without it and generate PRIMARY KEY automatically in mysqldb?

When I run the test in the sqltable appears new row with an ID with the following AUTO_INCREMENT value, while passed every time id 0.

**Entity**

```
@Data
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force = true)
public class Person {

    @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)// use or not - the same effect
    private int id;
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private String surname; 
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {     
    Person findByNameAndSurname(String name, String surname);
}
```

**Testing**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringRestInventoryPersistenceTests {

    @Autowired  
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Test
    public void personPersist() {
        Person person = new Person("John", "Smith");
        assertTrue(person.getId() == 0);
        personRepository.save(person);
        assertTrue(person.getId() == 0);
        Person person2 = personRepository.findByNameAndSurname("John", "Smith");
        assertEquals(person.getName(), person2.getName());      
    }//test passed
```

**mySql table**

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Because of default assigned generator

Comment: Your test never checks that your entity has an ID, which is the whole point of GeneratedValue.

Comment: As previous comment suggests, please add an assert before saving that id for person is 0 and an assert after saving that it is not 0. You'll probably find that you need the annotation. If not it is still good practice for portability.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue , I have added **sequence generator in DB** say 'idGenerator' ,and then add

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="idGenerator")
 @SequenceGenerator(name='dbname' , sequenceName="idGenerator")` ,

This will take the values from sequence generator created in DB

Answer (score 0):

I`ve understood the reason for this behavior. Without the @GeneratedValue annotation, ID is not generated automatically and ID with value 0 is always passed to the mysql database. In this case mysql generate ID value from AUTO_INCREMENT. This is default behavior.

To disable this behavior you can set next parameter:

SET SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'

Then after second call test method personPersist() we get error. In this case we can`t generate ID in mysql DB without @GeneratedValue annotation.